# JMeter AWS HTTPS SNI issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, apache-httpclient-4.x, amazon-cloudfront, sni

Is any way to get JMeter working with AWS HTTPS SNI ?

Right now when I'm trying to access my resource via HTTPS and CloudFront SNI enabled I receive a following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue of JMeter when using HTTPClient 4:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57935

So you have the option to switch to HttpClient3.1 implementation on the HTTP Request.

Edit 17 feb 2016:

- Issue is fixed in nightly build, it would be great if you could get it tomorrow and give feedback on wether it works with HTTPClient 4 for you

Comment: We have tried a few minutes ago to download the last nightly build and perform tests. Unfortunately the issue is still exists.

Comment: It is not yet available if using buildbot, you need to use this https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/ it is available only since few minutes

Comment: Thanks. Right now I'd like to confirm that the issue has gone ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi, sorry just to be sure (I have a doubt in my understanding of your sentence), do you confirm that issue is fixed in the last nightly build using HttpClient4 implementation ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This issue is fixed in the last nightly build - https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for your tests !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CloudFront supports SNI [1].  Are you sure you are sending the SNI header and using the supported ciphers [2]?   To verify, you can do the following:

- Take a TCP dump of your SSL connection attempt
- Look for 'Client Hello' message
- Ensure you see Extension: server_name
- Ensure that Server Name indication Extension had your server name set.

  1. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/05/amazon-cloudront-announces-sni-custom-ssl/
  2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers